# Calculating the Expected value of a function over a random vector

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

let $$(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$$ be the order statistics of $n$ i.i.d. uniform random variables. that satisfies the following condition. $$0 < x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n < 1$$
now consider a continuous function $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we define the random variable $R$ to be:
$$
R = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}f(X_{i+1}) \times (X_{i+1} - X_i) \hspace{0.5cm}X_0  = 0
$$
I need to prove the expected value of R equals:
$$
E[R] = \int_{0}^{1}f(t)(1-(1-t)^n)dt
$$
What I've tried so far is that I tried to find the pdf of each $X_i$ using the following formula:
$$
f_{X_k}(x_k) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}F_X^{k-1}(x)[1-F_X(x)]^{n-k}f_X(x)
$$
where $f_{X}$ is the pdf of our Uniform random variable(not to be mistaken with the f function described above) and F is the CDF of the aforementioned random variable. Using the said pdf and CDF and the linearity of expected value seems to get me nowhere, and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $0\le i\le n-1$,
$$
\mathsf{E}f(X_{i+1})(X_{i+1}-X_i)=\frac{1}{1+i}\mathsf{E}f(X_{i+1})X_{i+1}
$$
Thus,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}R&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1+i}\mathsf{E}f(X_{i+1})X_{i+1} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1+i}\int_0^1 f(x)xf_{X_{i+1}}(x)\, dx \\
&=\int_0^1 f(x)\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}{i}x^{i}(1-x)^{n-i}\, dx \\
&=\int_0^1 f(x)(1-(1-x)^n)\, dx
\end{align}
because $\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}x^{i}(1-x)^{n-i}=1$.

---

One can show the first equality by noticing that $(X_i,X_{i+1})\overset{d}{=}\big(U_{i}^{1/i}\cdots U_n^{1/n},U_{i+1}^{1/(i+1)}\cdots U_n^{1/n}\big)$, $1\le i\le n-1$, where $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ are i.i.d. $U[0,1]$ random variables and computing the expectation. That is, letting $Z\equiv U_{i+1}^{1/(i+1)}\cdots U_n^{1/n}$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}f(X_{i+1})(X_{i+1}-X_i)&=\mathsf{E}f(Z)Z\big(1-U_i^{1/i}\big) \\
&=\mathsf{E}[f(Z)Z]\times \mathsf{E}\big[1-U_i^{1/i}\big] \\
&=\mathsf{E}[f(Z)Z]\times \frac{1}{1+i}.
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand how the first equality was derived, and how it was used to calculate the expected value of R. (I would really appreciate it if you could add parentheses around E so I could know the scope of it)

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying your answer, but I still don't see how we can write the  kth order statistic as a product of nth roots of uniform distributions. I know that the kth order statistic sampled from an uniform distribution is a beta distribution itself, but I can't use that to proof what you have stated. I would appreciate it if you could prove that part, or cite some resources where I could read about it.

Comment: @nothatcreative5 I learnt this trick from [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=bSVGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&dq=uniform+order+statistics+representation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTysPzh433AhXO1qQKHYBxA9EQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=uniform%20order%20statistics%20representation) (Chapter4, p.43).